# Server crashes Sundays at 6 a.m. - out of memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, syslog

I have a weird problem: Every Sunday at 6 am my LAMP server crashes.
Looking at the logs I see about 500 apache2 processes at the time (this is a test server without any load - especially not at 6 am)

The syslog states the following:

```
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.304291] Out of memory: Kill process 912 (mysqld) score 31 or sacrifice child
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.304311] Killed process 912 (mysqld) total-vm:816528kB, anon-rss:6240kB, file-rss:0kB
```

It seems that the server is running out of memory thus killing some processes.

**What could be the problem?**
Does it possibly have something to do with the weekly crontab?

Here are some more lines from the syslog:

```
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290517] oom_kill_process: 3 callbacks suppressed
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290526] apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x280da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290534] apache2 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290541] Pid: 1884, comm: apache2 Not tainted 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290546] Call Trace:
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290561]  [<ffffffff810bf9ad>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x9d/0xb0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290570]  [<ffffffff8111a7e1>] dump_header+0x91/0xe0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290577]  [<ffffffff8111ab65>] oom_kill_process+0x85/0xb0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290584]  [<ffffffff8111af0a>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x220
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290592]  [<ffffffff8112098f>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x80f/0x820
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290603]  [<ffffffff8115937a>] alloc_pages_vma+0x9a/0x150
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290611]  [<ffffffff811399cc>] do_anonymous_page.isra.38+0x7c/0x2f0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290618]  [<ffffffff8113d3f1>] handle_pte_fault+0x1e1/0x200
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290625]  [<ffffffff8113d7c8>] handle_mm_fault+0x1f8/0x350
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290634]  [<ffffffff8165d3e0>] do_page_fault+0x150/0x520
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290642]  [<ffffffff81177d1d>] ? vfs_read+0x10d/0x180
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290649]  [<ffffffff8165a035>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290653] Mem-Info:
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290657] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290663] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290666] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290672] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 124
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290682] active_anon:73974 inactive_anon:73976 isolated_anon:0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290684]  active_file:305 inactive_file:3393 isolated_file:0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290687]  unevictable:0 dirty:11 writeback:4 unstable:0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290689]  free:12251 slab_reclaimable:2341 slab_unreclaimable:19263
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290692]  mapped:1006 shmem:37 pagetables:59627 bounce:0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290697] Node 0 DMA free:4652kB min:684kB low:852kB high:1024kB active_anon:4380kB inactive_anon:4380kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:36kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15656kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:8kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:200kB slab_unreclaimable:212kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:2024kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:12 all_unreclaimable? yes
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290720] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 991 991 991
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290728] Node 0 DMA32 free:44352kB min:44368kB low:55460kB high:66552kB active_anon:291516kB inactive_anon:291524kB active_file:1220kB inactive_file:13536kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1014992kB mlocked:0kB dirty:44kB writeback:8kB mapped:4024kB shmem:148kB slab_reclaimable:9164kB slab_unreclaimable:76840kB kernel_stack:5112kB pagetables:236484kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:5925 all_unreclaimable? yes
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290752] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290759] Node 0 DMA: 11*4kB 18*8kB 39*16kB 46*32kB 3*64kB 1*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4652kB
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290778] Node 0 DMA32: 54*4kB 119*8kB 121*16kB 79*32kB 49*64kB 26*128kB 12*256kB 7*512kB 3*1024kB 1*2048kB 5*4096kB = 44352kB
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290797] 10895 total pagecache pages
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290801] 7149 pages in swap cache
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290805] Swap cache stats: add 1460822, delete 1453673, find 653694/726620
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290809] Free swap  = 0kB
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.290812] Total swap = 2097084kB
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.299856] 261856 pages RAM
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.299860] 7335 pages reserved
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.299863] 291314 pages shared
May 19 06:00:11 myserver kernel: [313742.299866] 239474 pages non-shared
```

Comment: What is in the weekly crontab?  Root's?  Others in /var/spool/cron?

Comment: Hey @Ben, I think I found the problem: Apache had 500 MinSpareServers

Comment: Well setup some logging to start capturing what is going on Saturday night.

Comment: @horen, that is not really a problem.  Spare servers only get started if something is trying to use them.  Of course that is probably a value that is far too large for your system, but you need to look deeper to figure out why so many got started.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was the 500 MinSpareServers. The Load was >>10 the whole time on a single core test server. Thanks for your help though - I'll get back to next Monday ;)

Comment: Do you use a hosting control panel? If so which one?  Do you have logwatch, webalizer or any other stats processor installed.  What OS are you using?  I have a similar issue that happens on a CentOS 3 box.  I think it is semaphores not clearing on shutdown.

Comment: is 6 AM on SUnday when cron daily runs, by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the settings for Apache contained `MinSpareServers = 500` which led to a server load >>10 the whole time on a single core test server.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be caused by a badly tuned apache server.
You should never let apache resources grow more than your memory or CPU.

This reference is really interesting, might be worth take a look: http://drupal.org/node/215516

Answer (score 2):

One of my vSservers had a exactly a same problem.

It was hard to determin a exact reason for the crash caused by running of of the memory, but timing pointed to the crontab.weekly.

After a studying contents of the **crontab.weekly** from different servers, I found out that the problem server had a one script more that working servers did not have:

**apt-xapian-index**

It seemed that "maintenance tools for a Xapian index of Debian package" has caused a lot of problems on smaller servers and computers where it has been on use. After a doing some googling, I decided to remove the script from crontab.weekly and now the problem seems to be gone.

I suggest you trying to remove that and any other heavy-weight scripts from crontab.weekly to see if that helps with your problem :)